# How do I insert column into table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table and I'm trying to insert a column to the left and right of a given value on the first row. You can see a demo of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ismailp/vJvam/1/

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>tag 1</td>
            <td>tag 2</td>
            <td>tag 3</td>
            <td>tag 4</td>
            <td>tag 5</td>
            <td>tag 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some other value1</td>
            <td>Some other value1</td>
            <td>Some other value1</td>
            <td>Some other value1</td>
            <td>Some other value1</td>
            <td>Some other value1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've got it working for a single row in the table but not for n+1 rows. Could some jQuery Guru help me out here?

Comment: not getting you at all... you just have alert in you fiddle..

Comment: sorry...updated the link with: http://jsfiddle.net/ismailp/vJvam/1/

Comment: so you're trying to insert a column before/after the tag picked in the select menu?

Comment: Yes, I grab the value from the first tbody tr, as that serves as my "header", and what to add a columns for the same index for each following tr.

Comment: Could you try to use: :nth-child in post of :eq

Comment: Most of these solutions are just "add new cells to each row". That is not the same as adding a column. As soon as you start to have colspans, these become unreliable solutions.

Comment: @lightblade what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: @Ismailp Sorry, this is actually quite a complex problem. I once worked on this problem before at work, but didn't quite reach a solution. Luckily, the requirement didn't specify the table will have spans. The problem can get even more complex if you're going to factor in you can have a mixture of col and row spans. Since the browser's layout engine already knows how to lay it out, I think there should be a good solution by leaning on the layout engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wtD7x/)**

```
 $("tbody tr").each( function() {
   $(this).find("td:eq(" + cellBefore + ")").after("<td>" + spliceFirst + "</td>");
   $(this).find("td:eq(" + cellAfter + ")").after("<td>" + spliceLast + "</td>");
 });
```

Simplified: **[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/8UdQ9/)**

```
 $("tbody tr").each( function() {
    $(this).find("td:eq(" + column + ")").after("<td>" + spliceFirst + "</td>").before("<td>" + spliceLast + "</td>");
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep this simple, if you're just appending columns after, no need for crazy splitting etc.

This also doesn't depend on the value of the option.

```
$('select').change( function() {
    var option = $(this);
    var index = option.get(0).selectedIndex;
    var tr = $('#table tbody tr');
    var td = '<td class="red">FOO</td>';
    tr.each(function(){
        $(td).insertAfter($(this).find('td').eq(index));
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/vJvam/4/

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy is this what you wanted

```
$('select').change(function () {
   var selectedVal = $(this).val();
   // var column = $('td').filter(function() {
   //     return $(this).text() == selectedVal;
   // }).index();
   $('td').each(function () {
      if ($(this).text() === selectedVal) {
          $(this).before('<td>' + $(this).text() + '-before</td>');
          $(this).after('<td>' + $(this).text() + '-after</td>')
      }
   });
   //alert(column);
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/vJvam/2/) @ jsfiddle

Happy Coding:)

Comment: @Ismailp: i dont understand why you said that , but my code is working fine no matter how many ever rows.check this http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/vJvam/7/